# Angular 2 and Express Date format MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, angular

I'm using angular 2 and expressjs with mongodb and I'm retrieving this date format: **2016-06-02T14:20:27.062Z** but I need to show this: **06/02/2016 14:20:27**

**Express:**

models/user.js:

```
var userSchema = Schema({
// attributes
}, { timestamps: true });
```

routes/user.js:

```
router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) res.send(err)
    res.json(user)
  });
});
```

**Angular 2:**

user.service.ts:

```
getUser(id: number) {
   return this.authHttp.get(this.url + '/' + id)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

user.component.ts:

```
user: any;
getUser(id: number) {
 this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(
  user => this.user = user,
  error => this.errorMessage = error
 )
}
```

user.component.html:

```
{{ user.createdAt }} // appearing 2016-06-02T14:20:27.062Z but I need: 06/02/2016 14:20:27
```

Someone know how can I handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by changing the @YosvelQuintero answer doing:

user.component.html:

```
{{ stringAsDate(user.createdAt) | date:'dd MM yy HH:mm:ss' }}
```

user.component.ts:

```
stringAsDate(dateStr: string) {
  return new Date(dateStr);
}
```

Reference of the issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6336

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular2 you can specify a date format [DatePipe](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/DatePipe-class.html).

Code for your template:

```
{{ user.createdAt | date:'MM dd yy HH:mm:ss' }}   // output is '06/02/2016, 14:20:27'
```

And here you have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n9VG3pV5iDCTSnGL5dox?p=preview) with the solution working.

> Note: This pipe uses the Internationalization API. Therefore it is only reliable in Chrome and Opera browsers.

Comment: I have tried to do so This give me an exception Invalid argument '2016-06-02T16:41:15.214Z' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: I'm still having the same exception

Comment: You need to create a JavaScript Date instance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

I'm using moment.js (http://momentjs.com) for all my date formatting

user.component.ts:

```
formattedDate(date) {
    return moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
}
```

user.component.html:

```
{{ formattedDate(user.createdAt) }}
```